# Getting empty values in coverage report when using Gulp+Karma+Jasmine+Angular 4

Tags: angular, gulp, jasmine, karma-runner, gulp-plugin

I'm getting empty coverage report

Please find my gulpfile.js

```
            var gulp=require('gulp');
            gulp.task('hello',function(){
                console.log("Hello");
            });
            var tsc=require('gulp-typescript');
            var Server = require('karma').Server;
            var tsProjects=tsc.createProject('tsConfig.json');
            var open = require('gulp-open');
            /*
            * Run test once and exit
            */

            gulp.task('test', function (done) {
            return new Server({
                configFile:  __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
                action: 'run',
                singleRun: true,
                preprocessors: {
                    'src/app/accordion/*.js': ['coverage']
                },
                reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
                coverageReporter: {
                    type : 'html',
                    dir : 'coverage/',
                    subdir: '.'
                }
            }, done).on('error', function(err) {
            throw err;
            }).start();
            });

            gulp.task('compile-ts',function(){
                var sourceTsFiles=[
                './src/app/**/*.ts','./typings/**/*.d.ts'
                ]
                var tsResult=gulp.src(sourceTsFiles)
                .pipe(tsc(tsProjects));
                return tsResult.js
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/app/'));
            });

            gulp.task('coverage', ['test'], function() {
                return gulp.src('./coverage/js/index.html')
                    .pipe(open());
                });
```

After doing this I'm not getting any error when run using command '**gulp coverage**'

Before adding **coverage task** in code It was running all the test cases with only **test task**. But after adding **coverage task** its not even running test cases so getting empty coverage report.
But in the report I'm getting empty data
[image: Coverage Report]

Please let me know what's wrong with the **coverage task**. 
Thanks in advance.